# The csv writer is writing some un-realistic values to the csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

In my code, the csv-writer is writing some un-realistic values to the CSV file.

My goal is to read all csv files in one directory and put filter on any specific column and write the filtered dataframe to a consolidated csv file.

I am able to get the outputs as required in the VS console, but I am not able to write them into a csv file.

Kindly help to understand what I am doing incorrect.

This is my sample input:

[image]

And this is the output I am getting:

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import csv
from pandas.errors import EmptyDataError 
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder
path = os.getcwd()
#print(path)
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
print(csv_files)
col_name = input("Enter the column name to filter: ")
print(col_name)

State_Input = input("Enter the {}  ".format(col_name) )
print(State_Input)

df_empty = pd.DataFrame()

for i in csv_files:
    try:
        
        df = pd.read_csv(i)
        #print(df.head(5))

        State_Filter = df["State"] == State_Input
        print(df[State_Filter])
        df_child = (df[State_Filter])
        with open('D:\\PythonProjects\\File-Split-Script\\temp\\output\\csv_fil111.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
         data_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect = 'excel')
         
         for row in df_child:
            data_writer.writerows(row)
        
        
    except EmptyDataError as e:
        print('There was an error in your input, please try again :{0}'.format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_csv` to write your file at once. Prefer store your filtered dataframes into a list then concatenate all of them to a new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

data_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd()

# Your input here
state = input('Enter the state:  ')  # Gujarat, Bihar, ...
print(state)

data = []
for csvfile in data_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    df = df.loc[df['State'] == state]]
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('output.csv', axis=0)
```